# Icons in the Entity store

Tags: entity

with Mathematica 12 there are Icon entities. I was looking for standard Icons like Weight (standard kilogram icon) but could not find any. I have no clue what icons are available and the number of examples are exactly two.. Is there any way to get an overview of what icons images are available?

Comment: One way is `EntityList["Icon"]`.

Comment: Not _exactly_ on point, but I'd personally try to use [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/) icons over the "built-in" ones, because people will instantly recognize them from the web

Comment: @b3m2a1 Nice tip! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might take a while to run if the entities have not been cached locally.

```
EntityList["Icon"] // Map[#["Image"] &] // Partition[#, UpTo[27]] & //
  GraphicsGrid[#, Frame -> All, ImageSize -> 800] &
```

[image]